# SMD SOT-23-3 device identification - top marking E8LJ0

Tags: transistors, identification, surface-mount, markings

I have a small SOT-23 (3 pins, transistor-like) device that burned out (shorted between 2 pins). I need to identify it so I can replace it, but I can't find the code at all. The code is: **E8LJ0**

[image: photo showing unidentified component]

Thank you all.

Comment: nataf10 - Hi, FYI these are the current "[Component Identification Question Guidelines](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6710)". The more information you can supply from that list, the better the chances of identification e.g. what is the PCB? What can you tell us about nearby circuitry? Can you add another photo showing more of the PCB, to give more context? Have you reverse-engineered any of the schematic? If so, please add the results. By the way, did you remove that component from the PCB, before deciding it was shorted? If not, are you sure in-circuit measurements are correct?

Comment: http://www.dl7avf.info/charts/smdcode/ce.html#TOC reports E8## could be an EM Microelectronic V6340LSP3B+. I'd suggest pulling it, to make sure that is shorted and not a cap or other device.

Comment: Please add a bit more info. What is it sitting on? Knowing more about function allows more concise answers.

Answer (score 1):

Possible it's a Vishay [Si2338DS](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/427/si2338ds-1764946.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

It's a [Infineon IRLML6402](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRLML6402-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535668d5c2263c) P-Channel MOSFET.

[image]

[image]

(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/MOSFETs_Infineon-Technologies-IRLML6402TRPBF_C2593.html))